# Blazor WebAssembly: using Constructor injection for injecting Blazored.LocalStorage into a service

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-client-side

The package [Blazored.LocalStorage](https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage) is:

> a library to provide access to local storage in Blazor applications

Injecting the service into a component is easy:

```
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage
```

and if we want to inject it into the code behind:

```
[Inject]
private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }
```

But suppose I want to inject it into another service (let say for centralizing the control):

```
public class StorageManagement
{
    public StorageManagement(LocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        //How to initialize it here?
    }
}
```

I do not know how to initialize an instance of the service in the constructor of `StorageManagement` and also how to set the parameters of constructor of `StorageManagement` in Program.cs :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(e => new StorageManagement(//?));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();` or `builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage(config => config.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true);` as it's explain in [README](https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage/blob/master/README.md).
Then `builder.Services.AddScoped<StorageManagement>();` or `builder.Services.AddScoped(p => new StorageManagement(p.GetRequiredSerice<ILocalStorageService>()));`

But your service should take a `ILocalStorageService` not a `LocalStorageService` instance :

```cs
public class StorageManagement
{
    public StorageManagement(ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        //How to initialize it here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Per your suggestion, I put `builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(p => new StorageManagement(p.GetRequiredService<ILocalStorageService>()));` into Program.cs and `public StorageManagement(ILocalStorageService localStorage) ...` for the constructor but I'm getting this error: `Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService' from root provider.`

Comment: replace AddSingleton by AddScoped

Comment: @aguafrommars Why can't a singleton class resolve ILocalStorageService?  I have the exact issue and AddTransient solves the error but I really would like to have my class be a singleton (due to caching optimizations it has inside).

Comment: @Heems because `AddBlazoredLocalStorage` register `ILocalStorageService` as a scoped service. If you register `StorageManagement` as singleton it cannot be resolved because it needs a scope. That said, for a WASM app scoped and singleton have same lifetime. And for a server app you'd probably manage the cache per browser connection. It's why `ILocalStorageService`  is a scoped instance.

Comment: @aguafrommars Thank you for the explanation.  I used scoped in my WASM app and it's working as intended (i.e. one instance of my class).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Interface `ILocalStorageServer` in your constructor, it should be

```cs
public class StorageManagement
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService LocalStorage;
    
    public StorageManagement(ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        LocalStorage = localStorage;
    }
}
```